# ValueError: day is out of range for month datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have run into a problem with some code I have been writing. I take in four inputs ( day, month and year ) as a date, and times for how many times they want to repeat the task ( eg.  every Monday for 3 weeks ). The code is great however if the weeks differ between months I get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\dansi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\gui test 3.py", line 72, in addtimeslot
fulldateadd = datetime.date(year, month, day)
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Part of code that is relevant:

```
for i in range(0 , times):
    fulldateadd = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    cursor.execute( '''INSERT INTO dates (Date, Name, Start, End) VALUES( ?,?,?,? );''', (fulldateadd , name1, starttimehour, endtimehour))
    day = day + 7
    if day > 31:
        month = month + 1
```

I've tried to increment the month when the number of days are more than 31 however it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You aren't wrapping days back through zero anywhere..

Comment: That is a point. How would I go about coding that? I assume its finding the remainder however I don't know how to do that. Thanks for the reply

Comment: Increment a datetime with a timedelta inside your loop instead of trying to construct a new datetime on each iteration.

Comment: @Mitch never seen that before. I'll have a look and see if I can use that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several reasons why incrementing the *components* of a datetime and then creating a new one is not a good idea. Primarily because dealing with the Gregorian calendar yourself isn't that enjoyable IMHO, and datetime objects can do it for you.

On that note, a much more straightforward approach would be to add a timedelta to your datetime within the loop. For instance,

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> times = 4
>>> cur_date = datetime.date(2017, 2, 24)

>>> for _ in range(times):
        print('today is {0}, do something'.format(cur_date))
        cur_date += timedelta(days=7)

today is 2017-02-24, do something
today is 2017-03-03, do something
today is 2017-03-10, do something
today is 2017-03-17, do something
```

This could be placed in a generator as well, depending on your use case.

```
>>> for dt in (cur_date + timedelta(days=x*7) for x in range(times)):
        print('today is {0}, do something'.format(dt))

today is 2017-02-24, do something
today is 2017-03-03, do something
today is 2017-03-10, do something
today is 2017-03-17, do something
```

or with Pandas [`pd.date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/generated/pandas.date_range.html)

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> list(pd.date_range(start='2017-02-24', periods=4, freq='7D'))

[Timestamp('2017-02-24 00:00:00', freq='7D'),
 Timestamp('2017-03-03 00:00:00', freq='7D'),
 Timestamp('2017-03-10 00:00:00', freq='7D'),
 Timestamp('2017-03-17 00:00:00', freq='7D')]
```

---

Now what would happen if you attempted this example with your approach?

```
>>> year, month, day = 2017, 2, 24

>>> for i in range(0 , times):
        day = day
        fulldateadd = datetime.date(year, month, day)
        print('today is {0}, do something'.format(fulldateadd))
        day = day + 7
        if day > 31:
            day = day - 31
            month = month + 1

today is 2017-02-24, do something

ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-255-7df608ebbf8e> in <module>()
      1 for i in range(0 , times):
      2     day = day
----> 3     fulldateadd = datetime.date(year, month, day)
      4     print('today is {0}, do something'.format(fulldateadd))
      5     day = day + 7

ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

February doesn't have 31 days... so you would have to include a check with a mapping to the number of days in each month. Including logic for leap years.