# ValueError: day is out of range for month python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I am writing code that lets users write down dates and times for things they have on. It takes in the date on which it starts, the start time and finish time. It also allows the user to specify if they want it to carry over into multiple weeks (every Monday for a month for example)
I am using a for loop to do this, and because of the different months having different days I obviously want (if the next Monday for example is in the next month) it to have the correct date.

This is my code:

```
for i in range(0 , times):
    day = day
    month = month
    fulldateadd = datetime.date(year, month, day)
    day = day + 7
    if month == ( '01' or '03' or '05' or '07' or '10'or '12'):
        if day > 31:
            print(day)
            day = day - 31
            print(day)
            month = month + 1
        elif month == ( '04' or '06'or '09' or '11'):
            if day > 30:
                print(day)
                day = day - 30
                print(day)
                month = month + 1
        elif month == '02':
            if day > 29:
                print(day)
                day = day - 29
                print(day)
                month = month + 1
```

When running this and testing to see if it goes correctly into the new month I get the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\dansi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\gui test 3.py", line 73, in addtimeslot
fulldateadd = datetime.date(year, month, day)
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Like the commenter in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42673459/valueerror-day-is-out-of-range-for-month-datetime), I would recommend you use [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) for adding time to `datetime` objects. Then you don't have to worry about the month boundaries at all.

Comment: @glibdud I'm really new to datetime, as in school we've not really gone into much detail. I like the look of what it does, but I don't know a good way to implement it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's hard to be completely accurate without seeing some of the previous code (for example, where do `day`, `month`, `year`, and `times` come from?), but here's how you might be able to use `timedelta` in your code:

```
fulldateadd = datetime.date(year, month, day)
for i in range(times):
    fulldateadd = fulldateadd + datetime.timedelta(7)
```

A [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) instance represents a period of time, rather than a specific absolute time. By default, a single integer passed to the constructor represents a number of days. So `timedelta(7)` gives you an object that represents 7 days.

`timedelta` instances can then be used with `datetime` or `date` instances using basic arithmetic. For example, `date(2016, 12, 31) + timedelta(1)` would give you `date(2017, 1, 1)` without you needing to do anything special.

Comment: Perfect Explanation and answer. Thank you:) I know this isnt the place to ask but can I ask you to see if you can help with some other problems?